# Using exec to launch applications/accessories

Tags: c, linux, exec

I am new to Linux, and not an expert on c.

Despite numerous searches, I can't understand how to launch an application using exec.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    else if(cpid>0){
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"in parent",9);
    sleep(1);
    wait(NULL);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"CLOSE",5);
    exit(1);
    }
    else{ //child
    execl("menu://applications/Accessories","menu://applications/Accessories","Galculator",NULL);


          exit(1);
      }
```

Please guide me.
Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting. Check the return value of execl and call `perror`

Comment: The error that I am getting is No such file or directory @JesusRamos

Comment: @hek2mgl I have read the man page already, and unfortunately I am still stuck with the problem.

Comment: It was not meant rude. The man page helped me some days ago.. You are using a strange protocol `menu://`. Never heard of

Comment: @hek2mgl This is the path where accessories are located, and from those I want to launch the leafpad.

Comment: That does not seem like a valid path to me (looks like some kind of windows NFS path or something).

Comment: @hek2mgl can you please help me understand how to launch an application using exec. I would be grateful if you avoid using "int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);" etc to explain. I am still at a stage where this jargon is hard for me to understand

Comment: I don't understand `menu://`

Comment: @JesusRamos its the path where accessories are located (in LINUX). Please let me know why that path is wrong.

Comment: If this is on linux try `execl("galculator", "galculator", NULL);` I can't make heads or tails of what you're trying to do currently (launch Accessories with Galculator as an argument?)

Comment: That's not a file path, you seem to be referring to some GUI menu path from what I can tell (which won't work for obvious reasons).

Comment: @JesusRamos I am in the process of coding a program which will let users launch applications like gedit,firefox etc by typing, for instance, run leafpad or run galculator.

Comment: Will edit my answer a bit then.

Comment: @hek2mgl menu:// is where the path begins from. but apparently I am wrong, as I do not know where Galculator is installed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (argc != 2) /* [0] = "run", [1] = "app to run" */
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: run <app name>\n");
    exit(1);
}
const char *app = argv[1];
int ret;
ret = execl(app, app, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
    perror("execl");
```

Paths in Linux are based on the filesystem paths, it seems you're confusing that with paths returned by GUI elements in whatever window manager you're using. This should work if `galculator` is in your binpath (which it should be from what I can tell).

Comment: I tried what you asked me to but I am still getting no such file or directory error @JesusRamos

Comment: @user3015353 What exactly are you trying? Can you run `Galculator` from the terminal? Where is it installed? You're not giving enough information to help you out much here.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge. I will get back to you with correct information. Thank you for your help and time @JesusRamos